# Padding on multiple textFields

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm new in Objective c and i am facing a problem with padding in multiple text fields of a register form.
I have 4 text fields and this is my code and try to set left padding:

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 20)];
paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.textField1.leftView = paddingView;
self.textField1.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

self.textField2.leftView = paddingView;
self.textField2.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

self.textField3.leftView = paddingView;
self.textField3.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

self.textField4.leftView = paddingView;
self.textField4.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

The problem is that it crashes and i can't find why. Any help?

Comment: How can the same paddingView live in four different places? Maybe you should try making four different paddingViews.

Comment: Also if you are doing this just in order to pad the text field (i.e. set the margin of where its text starts) this is a really stupid way to do it. Make a custom text field subclass and override the methods provided for placing the text where you want it. That's what they are for! e.g. `textRectForBounds:`

Comment: I am really new in ios and have problem to understand how to implement this..

Comment: I believe it is best to learn before doing. That is why I have written two books that teach you iOS - if you are interested.

Comment: can you give me a link to those books?

Answer (score 1):

To reposition the text within the field, make a text field subclass something like this (I haven't actually run this code so you might need to tweak it):

```
@interface MyPaddedTextField : UITextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect r = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    r.origin.x += 5;
    r.size.width -= 5;
    return r;
}

@end
```

Comment: matt where i can put this? in my controller and works automatically?